# Elastic doesn't find the word with the apostrophe (')

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I try to find the sentence that consists the word with the apostrophe. So, in the text

> If you ask foreigners to name some typically English dishes, they
>   will probably say fish and chips and then stop. It is disappointing,
>   but true, that there is no tradition in Britain of eating in
>   restaurants, because our food doesn't lend itself to such preparation.
>   British cooking is found in the home, where it is possible to time the
>   dishes to perfection. So it is difficult to find a good English
>   restaurant with reasonable prices

I try to find

> find it is disappointing, but true, that there is no tradition in
>   britain of eating in restaurants, because our food doesn't

I create the query

```
{
"_index": "liza_index",
"_type": ".percolator",
"_id": "1594",
"_version": 37,
"found": true,
"_source": {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": {
                "span_or": {
                    "clauses": [{
                        "span_near": {
                            "in_order": true,
                            "clauses": [{
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "it"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "is"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "disappointing"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "but"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "true"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "that"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "there"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "is"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "no"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "tradition"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "in"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "britain"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "of"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "eating"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "in"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "restaurants"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "because"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "our"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "food"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "regexp": {
                                            "message": "doesn't"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }],
                            "slop": 0,
                            "collect_payloads": false
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

But the Elastic doesn't find it. Without the "doesn't" the query works.

I tried to add the backslash before the apostrophe - "doesn\'t" isn't valid, so I made "doesn\\'t" and "doesn\\\\'t". But it doesn't work.

By the way, I create the query with the one word "doesn't" with the backslashes and without

```
{
"_index": "liza_index",
"_type": ".percolator",
"_id": "2101",
"_version": 31,
"found": true,
"_source": {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "minimum_should_match": 1,
            "should": {
                "span_or": {
                    "clauses": [{
                        "span_multi": {
                            "match": {
                                "regexp": {
                                    "message": "doesn't"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

And it doesn't work too. At the same time the following queries work

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/liza_index/.percolator/1' -d '{"query" : {"match" : {"message" : "doesn't"}}}'
```

and

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/liza_index/.percolator/1' -d '{"query" : {"match" : {"message" : "doesn\\'t"}}}'
```

The question is: how can I find the word with the apostrophe? What kind of query should I create using the structure of the my first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “The hardest thing of all is to find a black cat in a dark room,
>   especially if there is no cat.”
>
> ― Confucius

Elasticsearch perform [standard analysis and curation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html#_built_in_analyzers) of data it receives. It removes most punctuation. If you use **match** query you will pass your query through same curation process and it will work (all punctuation from query will be removed). Regexp queries are not curated. That is why it can not find apostrophe.

Instead of generating complex regexp queries you could use **[match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html)**

```
curl -XPOST "http://esarchive.local:9200/liza_index/.percolator/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "message": "find it is disappointing, but true, that there is no tradition in britain of eating in restaurants, because our food doesn\"t"
    }
  }
}'
```

or create custom analyser/mapper to preserve puctuation

Comment: I have to find the regular expression patterns, that's why I can't use the match_phrase (as far as I can see, in the match_phrase I can't use the regular expressions). So, the correction of the tokenizer settings helps.
Thanks!